# Fetch API call request fails and receives 400 error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-code-400

I am trying to create a `fetch` call to a service but I keep getting 400 error,
As far as I understand, the 400 error says that there is something wrong with my request, and that the request I made is not what the server wanted **but** in postman I do manage to send that same query successfully.
I can't understand what is the problem.

The data looks to pass o.k.

In the console I receive, in addition to the 400 error, also this error:

> (index):76 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
> at HTMLButtonElement.submitData ((index):76)

this is line 76:

```
const result = await response.json();
```

This is my code:

```
<button id="send">Search</button>


<script>

    const sendToSd = document.getElementById('send');
    sendToSd.addEventListener('click', submitData);
   

    async function submitData(){
       
        const url = `http://siteurl/api/v3/requests?TECHNICIAN_KEY=123-123-123-132-123-&input_data=${JSON.stringify({
"request": {
    "subject": "test 25052020"
    "description": "I am unable to fetch mails from the mail server",
    "requester": {
        "id": "69094",
        "name": "dav"
    },
    "resolution": {
        "content": "Mail Fetching Server problem has been fixed"
    },
"status": {
                    "name":"open"
                },
    "template": {
        "name": "Test for API",
        "id": "123456789"
    }
}
}

    )}&FORMAT=json`;
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
            
        });
        
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log('result',result)

    }


</script>
```

Comment: The error you get in console only means that you can't convert the response to json. Is the api hosted by you? If yes, can we see the code?

Comment: Thanks. the api is hosted by me, it is a shelf product called serveicedesk plus. 
the issue is that in postman I send the exact same data and it works great

Comment: Can you show us the code? It may have a thing that returns this 400 error

Comment: If it's possible please send a link to the code or the code in Discord DMS : Koro~ (Baka)#7963

Comment: Two months later and still no answer. this is the format the API should receive

https://ui.servicedeskplus.com/APIDocs3/index.html#add-request

What is wrong with my json code?